# Bootstrap navbar change link TEXT on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have Bootstrap 4 navbar. There areseveral links with text in shortened form. Is it possible to change this shorten text with full text on hover? Full text is in the title element... Some small change animation would be a plus...

Thank you

```
<div class="desktop-menu-dropdown collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-desktop">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
<li><a href="" title='Human resources'>HR</a></li>
<li><a href="" title='Production department'>PD</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap tooltip to achieve this

example code

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">
      Tooltip on top
</button>
```